# Matlab structure arrays treated as vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I'd like my program to not treat this:

```
{0:1000}
{ones(1,1000)}
```

not as vectors when I input them for my structure array. Any idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?  Do you want them to b cell arrays, or not to be cell arrays?

Comment: I wonder if you describe the num2cell function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a complete other action of the function depending on the input type, you'll have to write a wrapper, catching off this input type. This is possible with the [isa](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/isa.html) function. It works as follows

```
if isa(var,'double')
    % do something with the double
elseif isa(var,'struct')
    % do something with the structure
else
    % ...
end
```

OR
maybe it's possible to avoid this wrapping and treat all variables alike, but then you'll have to provide a bit more information about this function and what you want it to do...